# How to stop function from returning new result until x seconds is over, and return previous result if called too soon

Tags: javascript

Creating a function `onceEvery()`, that allows a function to be called only once every x milliseconds. The first result is able to return, but the function doesn't stop it from being recalled before cooldown time is completed, returning the previous result instead. Thanks in advance!

```js
onceEvery =  function (func, wait) {
//return function then can only return every * seconds
  let cooldown = false;
  let result;
  let previous;
  //if called again while cooldown = true, return previous result
  if (!cooldown) {
    result = func;
    previous = result;
    beginCoolDown();
    return result;
  } else {
    return previous;
  }
  
  function beginCoolDown () {
    cooldown  = true;
    setTimeout (function () {
      cooldown = false;
    }, wait);
   }
  }
```

Comment: what is the issue with the code? do you have an example as well?

Comment: I think the question is a little confusing. Can you please add more details like the calling code and what are the outputs and what are the expected output instead?

Comment: Sure, I forgot to add the variables (which I've added now). Basically, the function onceEvery() should accept two variables  - func (a function) & wait (time in ms before the func can be called again).  Once the  function is called,  it should return the result, but can then not be called for 'wait' seconds (if it's recalled within this time, it returns the result of the previous call). I hope this is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by keeping track of the last result you provided and when you last provided it, *outside* the function, and then using that when the function is called to decide whether to update that information:

```
const minInterval = 5000;       // 5 seconds (for example)
let lastResult = null;          // Last result provided
let nextAvailable = Date.now(); // When the next can be provided
function onceEvery() {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (now < nextAvailable) {
        return lastResult;
    }
    lastResult = /*...calculate result...*/;
    nextAvailable = now + minInterval;
    return lastResult;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const minInterval = 5000;       // 5 seconds (for example)
let lastResult = null;          // Last result provided
let nextAvailable = Date.now(); // When the next can be provided
function onceEvery() {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (now < nextAvailable) {
        console.log(Date.now(), "Too soon, returning last value:", lastResult);
        return lastResult;
    }
    lastResult = (lastResult || 0) + 1;
    nextAvailable = now + minInterval;
    console.log(Date.now(), "Calculated new value:", lastResult);
    return lastResult;
}

// Call it every second or so
setInterval(onceEvery, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the concept of JavaScript closures. Return a wrapped function which executes only after waiting `wait` period.

To do this, maintain a flag `isCalled` on the outer function, which is initially `false` so that the function can be called immediately.

Once called the `isCalled` is set to `true` so that on next invocations the function has to wait until the timer executes and resets it to `false`:

```js
function onceEvery(func, wait) {
  let isCalled = false;
  let result;
  return () => {
    //if not called call the func
    if (!isCalled) {
      result = func();
      //set to true
      isCalled = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        //reset after waiting wait period
        isCalled = false;
      }, wait);
    }
    //return computed value
    //returns old value until new value is computed
    return result;
  }
}

let func = onceEvery(() => Date.now(), 2000);

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(func());
}, 400)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and code - got it working now! 
Would you mind explaining why the "let isCalled = false" at the top of the function wouldn't overrun the timeout if the function is recalled? Hope that made sense..

Comment: Because the onceEvery is called only *once*, once called it returns an inner function which is the actual function being invoked multiple times. This inner function forms a closure which has access to the state of the outer function's isCalled variable, so every time you call the inner func, it merely uses and sets the isCalled variable but never declares it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define function beginCoolDown() outside of the onceEvery(), and move the definition of the cooldown outside of the function.
That would be look like this:

```js
let cooldown = false
function beginCoolDown() {
...
}
function onceEvery() {
...
}
```